# Replication issue - CREATE SELECT alternative?

Tags: mysql, replication, ddl

I've an MySQL 5.1 **slave** for our BI team.

They need to make some CREATE SELECT with big select queries (several million lines).

As CREATE SELECT is a DDL, if the replication attempts to update some rows in same tables than the SELECT statement, replication is blocked until the freeing of the CREATE SELECT.

Do you now a good non-blocking alternative to thoses CREATE SELECT statements?

I thought to an SELECT INTO OUTPUT FILE then LOAD DATA INFILE but they will fill out our disks as BI guys like to do... :)

Max.

Comment: Is the `CREATE SELECT` from a single table or a complex join ? Please post the query you have.

Comment: Complex joins (8-10 tables it's not a particular query)

Comment: Are all the tables InnoDB (please say yes) ???

Comment: I think so (pretty sure), i don't have a sample query, we have some MyISAM tables but i think the problem came from the CREATE statement that create a transaction and blocks rows until it'is done.